# Setting boundaries for gesture-detector drag

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to make drag only in the image so there are boundaries on each side of the widget, so the user may not drag out-of-bounds.

here is the stack and the image below , i want the gesture detectors dosen't surpass the image
please can anyone help me achieve this !

Here's the code:

```
Column Team1() {
   return Column(
     children:[ **\[**][1]
       Stack(
         children: [
           Image.asset(
             "assets/field.jpg",
             height: 500,
             fit: BoxFit.cover,
           ),
           for (var i in LineupList)
             Positioned(
               left: i["offset"].dx,
               top: i["offset"].dy,
               child: Padding(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: i["left"], top: i["top"]),
                 child: GestureDetector(
                     onTap: () {
                       ShowPlayer();
                     },
                     onPanUpdate: (details) {
                       setState(() {
                         i["offset"] = Offset(
                             i["offset"].dx + details.delta.dx,
                             i["offset"].dy + details.delta.dy);
                       });
                     },
                     child: new Container(
                       width: 50.0,
                       decoration: DottedDecoration(
                           shape: Shape.box,
                           color: Colors.white,
                           strokeWidth: 3),
                       child: new Column(children: [
                         SizedBox(
                           height: 50,
                         ),
                       ]),
                     )),
               ),
             ),
         ],
       ),
       Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Text(
               "REMPLAÇANTS",
               style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 112, 112)),
             ),
             Row(
               children: [
                 new Container(
                   width: 50.0,
                   decoration: DottedDecoration(
                       shape: Shape.box,
                       color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 152, 152),
                       strokeWidth: 3),
                   child: RawMaterialButton(
                       constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(26, 26)),
                       onPressed: () {},
                       child: IconTheme(
                         data: IconThemeData(
                             color: Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 152, 152),
                             size: 16),
                         child: Icon(Icons.add),
                       )),
                 )
               ],
             )
           ],
         ),
       )
     ],
   );
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few key factors to control the object in two dimension.

- every object on On UI must be 2D and calculate accordingly.
- Tap event will get on single point, to place object center you need to minimize the of object half size. same goes for boundary.
- if you like to have free axis movement   place logic separately, don't combine x and y-axis logic with and operator.

There are many more, you can check [this as an example](https://github.com/yeasin50/space_craft/blob/master/lib/feature/on_play/utils/helpers/player_movement_handler.dart)

```dart
class BoundaryTest extends StatefulWidget {
  BoundaryTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BoundaryTest> createState() => _BoundaryTestState();
}

class _BoundaryTestState extends State<BoundaryTest> {
  double dx = 100, dy = 100;

  Size containerSize = const Size(100, 100);
  Size? screen;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          // box allowed 90% of body from center
          final boxSize =
              Size(constraints.maxWidth * .9, constraints.maxHeight * .9);

          screen ??= Size(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
          return Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Align(
                child: Container(
                  width: boxSize.width,
                  height: boxSize.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 4)),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: dy,
                left: dx,
                child: Container(
                  width: containerSize.width,
                  height: containerSize.height,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  final tapPos = details.globalPosition;

                  if (tapPos.dx <
                          screen!.width * .95 - (containerSize.width / 2) &&
                      tapPos.dx - (containerSize.width / 2) >
                          screen!.width * .05) {
                    //moveable to x
                    dx = tapPos.dx - (containerSize.width / 2);
                    setState(() {});
                  }
                  if (tapPos.dy <
                          screen!.height * .95 - (containerSize.height / 2) &&
                      tapPos.dy >
                          screen!.height * .05 + (containerSize.height / 2)) {
                    //moveable to
                    dy = tapPos.dy - containerSize.height / 2;
                    setState(() {});
                  }

                  debugPrint(tapPos.toString());
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this image, the purple box is only allowed to move within the red area. And you can think the different way of decorating your logic
[image]

Comment: how to adapt this concept to mine ?

Comment: Did you run this snippet?

Comment: yep it works , but in my case the borders are the image itself.

Comment: yes you can calculate  it by wrapping with sizedBox and providing height 500 and also you need to measure the width of the image

Comment: I did that and it worked , but there is one thing that disturbs . when i click on the container to drag it it goes below automatically , do you have any idea what is wrong ? thank you in advance !

Comment: You can use `onTapDown`